Java KeyEvent and ArrayList Issue
I am writing code for a personal project that takes data from a CSV file, and passes it to an editable JCombobox that then displays names of airports.
Having done that - I want to write the quality of life feature where you start to type and the names slowly filter down until it matches what you are looking for (suggested text.)
When I run this code the first time everything goes smoothly, the suggested text system works in a rudimentary way, and then it resets with no issues when you delete what you have searched.
However, every time I perform a second search, everything resets properly except for the ArrayList 'tempArray'.
I have tried moving it outside of the keyEvent, thinking I am not fulling understanding how it is being called.
Yet, no matter where I put it, or however many debug statements I throw in, all of the code works properly except for that specific arrayList 'tempArray'.
The bufferedChars string has a value, the airportNames arrayList holds all of it's same values.
I have scoured the web and documentation but I am clearly missing a fundamental part of what is going on. Any help is appreciated and all I want is to be pointed in the right direction, I am not asking for code.
Thank you.
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class WindowEngine extends csvLoader implements ActionListener{

    protected String originDataToSendToScraper, destinationDataToSendToScraper;
    protected TextField destinationTextField;
    protected JComboBox originComboBox;

    String bufferedChars = "";
    ArrayList<String> tempArray = new ArrayList<>();

    MyDebug debug = new MyDebug();

    public void drawWindow()
    {
        //Make Base Frame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Pilot's Club");
        Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        frame.setSize(screenSize);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        frame.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        //Make left Side panel
        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();





        //Origin Info
        JLabel originLabel = new JLabel("Origin: ");
        originLabel.setSize(50,25);
        originLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        //Set array elements from csv and add them to the combobox
        originComboBox = new JComboBox(airportNames.toArray());
        originComboBox.setSize(50,25);
        originComboBox.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        originComboBox.setToolTipText("Origin Airport: ");
        originComboBox.setEditable(true);
        originComboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            //used to debug amount of times code has been run
            int ran = 0;

            //key events for the Jcombobox
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event) {

                if(event.getKeyChar() != KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)
                {
                    if(originComboBox.getModel().getSize() < airportNames.size())
                    {
                        originComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(airportNames.toArray()));
                        bufferedChars = "";
                        debug.log("RESET INITIATED");
                    }

                        bufferedChars += event.getKeyChar();
                        System.out.println("Added: " + bufferedChars);

                }
                if(event.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && !bufferedChars.isEmpty())
                {
                    ran +=1;

                    bufferedChars = bufferedChars.replace(" ", "");
                    System.out.println("Search Key: " + bufferedChars + " : search #: " + ran);

                    tempArray = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (String name : airportNames) {
                        if (name.contains(bufferedChars)) {
                            tempArray.add(name);
                        }
                    }
                    originComboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(tempArray.toArray()));
                    System.out.println(tempArray.toString());
                }
            }
        });


        //Destination Info
        JLabel destinationLabel = new JLabel("Destination: ");
        destinationLabel.setSize(50,25);
        destinationLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
        destinationTextField = new TextField(25);
        destinationTextField.addActionListener(this);

        //Add buttons and labels
        leftPanel.add(originLabel);
        leftPanel.add(originComboBox);
        leftPanel.add(destinationLabel);
        leftPanel.add(destinationTextField);


        //Add panel to frame
        frame.add(leftPanel);

        //set visible last
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
    {
        originDataToSendToScraper = originComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
        System.out.println("Sent origin data to scraper.. ");

        destinationDataToSendToScraper = destinationTextField.getText();
        System.out.println("Sent destination data to scraper.. ");

        ScrapeAirportData scrapeAirportData = new ScrapeAirportData();
        scrapeAirportData.getUserInfo(originDataToSendToScraper, destinationDataToSendToScraper);
    }

}


The first search goes properly and the reset always works properly, but the suggested text feature fails to function after an initial search.

Use a DocumentListener not a KeyListener.

@HovercraftFullOfEels I was able to implement the correct implementation with a document listener to grab the text updates using a JTextField wrapper around the JComboBox and then use a keylistener to update the ComboBox. Thank you.
